# Google analytics in offline mode

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, offline

I have developed one intranet application using asp.net. Now this web app is going to use in train. I have implemented Google Analytics in my site. Now there is not sufficient internet connectivity in train so my client wants me to do Google Analytics in offline mode.  So once internet is available, application will post all saved data to Google.

Now I have no idea how I will achieve this. If any one has any idea or any such software in mind then please help me.

Comment: One question, how they see the page if they are not connected ?

Comment: My application is intranet application. So user can see all data as far as user is in train. But for posting data to google analytics, there must be internet connection on server. But sometimes internet connection is not available in train so analytics will not work

Comment: any news on this, looking for something similar